# How to pass path for static files to js file in django

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-forms

I have Django project where formset use javascript. I have js file where I have to pass path to static file - icon, to show icon for uploaded image before update on backend side.

Here is my code:

```
if(name.substring(name.lastIndexOf(".")+1) == 'mp4'){
  self.$image.attr('src', 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2f/Google_2015_logo.svg' );
```

How I can pass here STATIC_FILE variable?
Please for any hint.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

in template

```
{% load static from staticfiles %}
{% static "Google_2015_logo.svg" %}
```

Make sure STATIC_URL is configured in settings.py

Comment: Is this a solution when you refer to the static using JavaScript?